# Java Garbage Collector Different Behavior Across Virtual Machines

Tags: java, garbage-collection, virtual-machine, heap-memory

I am using the Java G1GC garbage collector with the same configuration across multiple VMs but am noticing different GC behavior. Specifically, the young GC process is happening less frequently on some VMs than on others. All VMs are taking the same amount of traffic (equally load balanced) and they perform identical functions. So it seems the differences aren't due to application functionality.

The behavior can largely be broken up into two categories. In one category of VMs, the heap size is kept tight and consistent. The heap will stay at around 50% capacity and the young GC process runs when it approaches 60%. The other category of VM shows the heap consistently following a pattern of approaching 80-90% capacity and then young GC runs and brings it back down to ~50%.

Are there factors on the system level that could contribute to this GC behavior (with all else being equal)?

Comment: same jre everywhere? other than that - the traffic payload is probably different, causing different behavior.

Comment: Yeah same JRE version essentially the same traffic patterns

Comment: @CoreyPoggioli, by different VM do you mean different OS? If you can share the JVM parameters and GC logs in these VM it will help.